# ByteIO() file in python can not upload to the Bitbucket and function calls again and again

Tags: python, bitbucket

I have two functions that they can call each other, one of them is the upload function, which uploads the files to Bitbucket, one of those uploaded files is dragged and dropped by the user and another one is the result of the concatenation of dragged and dropped file with another file in another directory, dragged and dropped file was uploaded to the Bitbucket correctly but the result of the concatenation of files in another function(the name of the function is gbl_delta_historization_api) couldn't upload to Bitbucket(the type of this file should be BytesIO) and this function calls again and again by upload function and for stop it I should kill the script, in the following code you can see a part of upload function:

```
 def upload(
        self, belle_type: str, environment: str, user: str, token: str,
        project: str, repo: str, branch: str, file,
        filename="auto", overwrite=False
    ) -> str:
    if belle_type == "gbl_delta_business":
            file.seek(0)
            return gbl_delta_historization_api(
                git_login=user,
                git_write_token=token,
                file=file.read(),
                upload=self.upload,
                enviro=environment,
                belle_type=belle_type,
                belle_git_project=project,
                belle_git_repo=repo,
                belle_git_branch=branch
            )
    return fn if res.status_code in [200, 409] else ""
```

The name of another function is gbl_delta_historization_api and this function calls the upload function two times at the beginning and end of the function, and it likes the below:

```
def gbl_delta_historization_api(
    git_login, 
    git_write_token,
    file,
    upload,
    enviro='uat',
    #filename='dqchecks_belle_gds_uat.csv',
    belle_type='gbl_delta_business',
    belle_git_project='DQM',
    belle_git_repo='dqm-belle-repo',
    belle_git_branch='master'
):

 #some codes for the calculation and concatenation of files are here

        df_real_out_buffer = BytesIO()
        df_real_out.to_csv(df_real_out_buffer, sep=";", index=False)

        # call the function that was passed as an argument
        return upload(
            belle_type="gbl_delta_business" if enviro=="prod" else "gbl_delta_uat_business",
            environment=enviro,
            user=git_login,
            token=git_write_token,
            project=belle_git_project,
            repo=belle_git_repo,
            branch=belle_git_branch,
            file=df_real_out_buffer,
            filename="auto",
            overwrite=False
        )
    else:
        return res2.status_code
    return
```

how can I fix this issue? actually, the result of the concatenation is the data frame and correct result but for uploading the file to Bitbucket we need BytesIO file

Comment: One potential problem here is that the `to_csv` operation is going to leave the fake file positioned at end of file.  You might try `df_real_out_buffer.seek(0)` before you call upload.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your comment I tried it, it didn't call function like a loop but I got this error: "upload file to Bitbucket failed"

Comment: Where is the upload being done?  All I see here is two functions that will call each other inifinitely.